# Meteor testing app using local server and custom ip

Tags: javascript, mobile, meteor, server

I'm developing an meteor application client/server and app, too.
when i compile my application using this command:

```
meteor run ios-device --mobile-server 192.168.2.126
```

App on device cannot connect to server (my server is on local network) and return this error in javascrip console:

```
Failed to load resource: Could not connect to the server.
```

If i use:

```
meteor run ios-device
```

it works perfecly.

Why?
I need to have application installed on different server in different network. The server has always the same ip: 192.168.2.126.. I need my client/app application works when is connected to one of my local network..

Answer (score 0):

Solved, i have to use this format per server url:

```
http://192.168.2.126:3000
```