# Meteor test/deploy iOS app to connect with real server (not localhost)

Tags: javascript, ios, node.js, meteor

I have a meteor application that I have been testing on an iOS phone. I deployed the application originally with the following (based on [this guide](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/running-on-mobile)):

```
meteor install-sdk ios    
meteor add-platform ios
meteor run ios

meteor run ios-device
```

However, this is just using a local version, hosted on `http://localhost:3000`. So I have been reading about [how to deploy to a specific server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32224239/meteor-testing-app-using-local-server-and-custom-ip), examining a [number](https://forums.meteor.com/t/meteor-run-ios-device-mobile-server-not-working/9921) of [different](http://www.yauh.de/the-illustrated-guide-to-mobile-apps-with-meteor/) instruction [sites](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/How-to-submit-your-iOS-app-to-App-Store) about the topic. From this it seems that I should simply run the following, where `http://example.com` is the server location:

```
meteor run ios-device --mobile-server http://example.com
```

However, the application is still running on the local server. In the `config.xml` there are the two following lines next to each other:

```
<access origin="http://meteor.local/*"/>
<access origin="*://example.com/*"/>
```

so I tried deleting `<access origin="http://meteor.local/*"/>`, but that didn't fix it.

I then added the following to the root of my meteor project in a file named `mobile-config.js`, based on [this example](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/examples/todos/mobile-config.js),

```
App.info({
  name: 'Example',
  description: 'An iOS app built with Meteor',
  version: '0.0.1',
  author: 'Me',
  website: 'http://example.com/'
});

App.icons({
  // iOS
  'iphone': 'resources/icons/icon-60.png',
  'iphone_2x': 'resources/icons/icon-60@2x.png',
  'ipad': 'resources/icons/icon-76.png',
  'ipad_2x': 'resources/icons/icon-76@2x.png'
});

App.launchScreens({
  // iOS
  'iphone': 'resources/splash/Default~iphone.png',
  'iphone_2x': 'resources/splash/Default~iphone.png',
  'iphone5': 'resources/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png',
  'ipad_portrait': 'resources/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png',
  'ipad_portrait_2x': 'resources/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png',
  'ipad_landscape': 'resources/splash/Default-Landscape~ipad.png',
  'ipad_landscape_2x': 'resources/splash/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png'
});

App.accessRule('example.com/*')
```

The application compiles, but its still running on localhost. Also, the app icon and spash screen are the meteor defaults, not my custom icons/splash screens (which are in the root folder in `resources/econs/...png` and `resources/splash/...png`, so perhaps the compiling process is ignoring everything that is in `mobile-config.js`?

So the question boils down to "How can I run this iOS application using the live server?"

Comment: Hope you don't mind if I ask why you want to try to run an iOS application on a live server

Comment: did your problem get solved? I tried linking it to a remote server. And it works for me without any problem. Maybe you could rebuild your app using mobile-server

Answer (score 0):

You can build your app to connect to the production server

`meteor build /tmp/example-build --server=http://example.com`

After that side load it onto your device.